# Unable To Multiply Two Dataframes in Pandas Based On Common Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I have been trying to figure out how I can multiply two dataframes together based on the common index. The second dataframe is just a subset of the first dataframe and I want to multiply the second dataframe by the first dataframe.

I have tried `.mul()` but I am always either getting a matrix with `NaN` or an error that says `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`. I have also tried using the `map()` function but I have not been able to find any good tutorials to help my understanding of how to execute a multiplication based on the index values.

Ideally I want an output where the indexes from Dataframe 2 match Dataframe 1, and the resulting values under each column are just a simple multiplication of the corresponding values.

```py
Dataframe #1

            branch    fineroot     foliage
trm                                       
002015   35.111533   35.111533   35.111533
002025   55.359203   55.359203   55.359203
002304         NaN         NaN         NaN
003015  356.592903  356.592903  356.592903
```

```py
Dataframe #2

            branch    fineroot
trm                           
002025   55.359203   55.359203
002304         NaN         NaN
003015  356.592903  356.592903
```

```py
Expected Result

trm           branch             fineroot
002025   (55.359*55.359)      (55.359*55.359)
002304        NaN                    NaN
003015    (356.59 * 356.59)  (356.59 * 356.59)
```

Comment: It seems that Pandas keeps trying to multiply the index values as well which just seems like it should not be occuring.

Comment: thanks, so do you mean `df1.mul(df2).fillna(df1)`? what is your expected output?

Comment: @anky That solution results in the error ```TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'```

Comment: But not for the example you provided. there is some issue with your data which you should look into and edit the example. There are mixed dtypes I think, just a guess

Comment: @anky The `trm` column is considered as an 'object', but everything else is considered as floats. So it seems like the `trm` is trying to be multiplied with a float, but I can't understand why this would happen.

Comment: Another way I could approach this would be to create a loop that goes through the index values and if the index values match, then multiply the individual df1[i,j] value by the df2[i,j] value. But this computation is not efficient at all.

Comment: Loops not required so far i think. which df has object as index and which has int as index?

Comment: @anky Only the `trm` column has `dtype = object` , all of the other columns are floats. Only the floats should be multiplying because the `trm` is just supposed to act as an index ID.

Comment: so then `trm` is not an index? your example shows `trm` as index. hence asking. `df1.set_index('trm').mul(df2.set_index('trm'))` ?

Comment: @anky Unfortunately this is the result that returns a dataframe of NaN

Comment: may be provide us `df1.head()` and `df2.head()` I guess I cant debug further loos like a little unclear. or dtype doesnt match in df1 vs df2 index

Comment: Fwiw, I built dataframes to match the data you described, set the index to `trm` in each, and `df1.mul(df2)` worked to give your answer (also indexed by `trm`), with the addition of a `foliage` column full of `NaN` values. Agreed with anky that your datatypes or something seem off.

Comment: Could I ask what your dtypes ended up being?